# Mongo DB get query to sub element

Tags: mongodb

I have this document:

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5eb5abacce591715f9c6cf72"),
  "title" : "Fight Club",
  "writer" : {
      "name" : "Chuck Palahniuk",
      "age" : 57.0,
      "children" : 0.0,
      "hometown" : "Burbank"
  },
  "year" : 1999.0,
  "rating" : 9.0,
  "actors" : [ 
      {
          "name" : "Brad Pitt",
          "age" : 55.0,
          "children" : 6.0,
          "hometown" : "Springfield"
      }, 
      {
          "name" : "Edward Norton",
          "age" : 49.0,
          "children" : 1.0,
          "hometown" : "Columbia"
      }
  ]
}
```

I need to search by writer -> name and apply $eq
I don't know how can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following function you can find the record you need searching by the writer's name.

```
db.movies.find({ 'writer.name': 'Quentin Tarantino' });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [query nested fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#specify-equality-match-on-a-nested-field) using the dot notation:

```js
db.collection('movies').find({
  'writer.name': 'Chuck Palahniuk'
});
```